# Sur la préposition « sur » avec ces verbes

Tags: prépositions, verbes

> « Je ne céderai [sur](http://www.lemonde.fr/election-presidentielle-2017/article/2017/05/14/emmanuel-macron-a-l-elysee-pour-son-investiture_5127476_4854003.html) rien des engagements pris vis-à-vis des
>   Français ».

Je n'arrive pas à comprendre pourquoi Emmanuel Macron a utilisé la préposition *sur* en lieu et place de la préposition *à* qui suit toujours le verbe *céder* : *céder à*.

Je n'ai vu nulle part, dans aucun dictionnaire, le verbe *céder* être suivi par la préposition *sur* en lieu et place de la préposition *à*.

**Addendum**

Et encore dans cette phrase :

> Monsieur le président, on vous attend [sur](http://www.la-croix.com/France/Politique/Francois-Soulage-Monsieur-president-vous-attend-inegalites-2017-05-11-1200846400) les inégalités.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The « céder » here is an intransitive verb. As such, a preposition does not necessarily follow.

The preposition « sur » is related to the « rien » and has the meaning of "***on/about*** nothing/anything".

---

The same goes for the « sur » in:

> Monsieur le président, on vous attend **sur** les inégalités.

This headline conveys the message that:

> On attend de vous que vous traitiez le problème des inégalités à la racine.